# Facebook API search - Can't see all the users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to search FB users with this API Query:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=test%20user&type=user&&access_token=valid_user_access_token

But I only get a partial result list (even when i check all the pages).
when i'm searching directly through facebook search bar - I get more results, why is that?
what can i do in order to get all the users in the API Query?

Answer (score 0):

Es wäre hilfreich Benutzer mit dem Familiennamen zu suchen . Auch nur it ehemaligem Arbeitgeber oder einer Schule die Diese mal besucht haben . Finde hie KEINE alten Freund !!! Gruß Rolf

Comment: Please, try to write it in English.